# Adaptive Card - Action.OpenUrl not working on web browser

Tags: adaptive-cards

I'm trying to develop an adaptive card layout which can be integrated in web application.
I have developed the entire layout but the action event for opening URL(`Action.OpenUrl`) is not working.

Other actions such as `Action.ToggleVisibility` is working fine.

Here is a [code pen](https://codepen.io/santhosh1248/pen/RwJMLXB) for the same.

What I have noticed is, an **alert is being triggered** on the adaptive cards website/adaptive card designer for these tutorials but redirection is not working even on that website.

please let me know if I'm have to do something else to make the url open in new window.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/actions), "By default, the actions will render as buttons on the card, but it's up to your app to make them behave as you expect. Each SDK has the equivalent of an OnAction event that you must handle."

I found this initially a bit head-scratching as I felt it's something that should've just worked out of the box. Fortunately, it's fairly straight-forward to implement. In the code that displays the adaptive card, just before the adaptivecard.render() call, this is what I used:

```
adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = (action: Action) => {
  if (action instanceof OpenUrlAction) {
    window.open(action.url, '_blank');
  }
}
```

[More details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/actions) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1070849/adaptive-card-action-openurl-does-nothing) also helped me.